# Как сделать луч из центра камеры

Tags: unity3d

Нужно сделать, чтобы луч исходил из центра камеры, в ту сторону, куда она смотрит (по середине), к сожалению не знаю как, и желательно сделать, чтобы луч двигался, когда камера разворачивалась.

Comment: `Raycast` - вам как луч, `Screen.height/2`, `Screen.width/2` вам с центра экрана. Во время движения экрана создавайте событие и с помощью обработчика при движении выпускайте новый луч.

Comment: Понимаю что не лучший ответ, но я сейчас не перед компьютером, поэтому написал как комментарий а не как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей подходит [Camera.ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html). Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
Vector3 Ray_start_position = new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, 0);

private void releaseRay () {
    // Сам луч
    Ray ray = main_camera.ScreenPointToRay(Ray_start_pos);
    // Запись объекта, в который пришел луч, в переменную
    Raycast hit; 
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);

    
}
```

Сам объект можно получить с помощью `hit.collider.gameObject`